# My website covers the background on chrome but not IE

Tags: css

My website covers the background on chrome, but not IE.

I've tried looking around, tried some javascript, alongwith some other HTML solutions, but none seemed to work and they were also quite old.

This is my CSS:

```
body {
    background-image:url("images/splash.png");
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: `tried a javascript thingy` Brilliant. Truly inspired. Have you considered writing a paper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set width and height for body.
Need to set [background size](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp).

```
body {
    background-image:url("images/splash.png");
    background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

you can try also this

```
background:url("images/splash.png") 0 0 / 100% auto no-repeat fixed;
```

so if you using IE8 can try this

```
body {
  position: fixed; 
  top: 0%; 
  left: 0%; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader( src='images/splash.png', sizingMethod='scale');
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader( src='images/splash.png', sizingMethod='scale')";
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I'm still in a similar position though.
using  background-image:url("images/splash.png");
        `background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-size:cover;` works on chrome but not IE :/ (I can't seem to get code formatting working)

Comment: Yes I did. I'm starting to think it's possibly a problem with my IE?

Comment: and which version you are using? Because background-size is only for IE9+

Comment: Yes i'm running IE8, I would assume a lot of people are still using IE8 and so I probably need to get it sorted

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried either of these?

http://www.minimit.com/articles/code-tips/perfect-responsive-fullscreen-backgrounds

http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: Thanks for the help, it still leaves me in the same boat. Is it possible that it's only a problem on my end with IE? I can get my friends to test it I guess.